# Get Type from Fully qualified name only in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, reflection, windows-8, windows-store-apps, .net-assembly

I have a string containing a full qualified name like `MyNamespace.MyType` which I know is in a loaded assembly.

I need to get the `Type` instance of this, in a windows store app.

The issue I'm having is that while there is some reflection classes in windows store apps, it's very limited, and I simply can't use what I've been using for a desktop app.

If I can get an assembly I can find my type within it so I'm currently trying to get all loaded assemblies, which I can't do easily as `AppDomain` doesn't exist.

I found the following:

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IEnumerable<Assembly>> GetAssembliesCore()
{
    var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

    List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
    foreach (Windows.Storage.StorageFile file in
                 await folder.GetFilesAsync().AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        if (file.FileType == ".dll")
        {
            AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName() { Name = file.Name };
            Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(name);
            assemblies.Add(asm);
        }
    }

    return assemblies;
}
```

I added the `.AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false)` to stop it hanging, but it now fails trying to load the assembly:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'FDE.Audio.dll' or one of its dependencies.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.":"FDE.Audio.dll"

Is there something I need to set up in the manifest? Something else?

How can I load an assembly in my program's folder (`AppX` I think)?

Comment: Note that I originally tried walking the assembly references tree using `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` and `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()`, but they aren't available in a store app. Also, I can't easily get the assembly qualified type name (eliminating the need to get all assemblies) as for various complicated reasons when I get the types as a string it's in a different assembly compared to when read it.

Comment: `Type.GetType("MyNamespace.MyType")` doesn't work?

Comment: No, it needs to be assembly qualified or in the current one, which it isn't.

Comment: Is the Type you need inside FDE.Audil.dll? If not, you could just try/catch and skip over it to ensure that you get the assembly you need.

Comment: It could be in any of the dlls that are part of my project, so I need to be able to load them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to extract file name without extension

```
var filename = file.Name.Substring(0, file.Name.Length - file.FileType.Length);

AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName() { Name = filename };
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(name);
```